# POWERSHELL - Three arrays of different legths, how can I create an HTML output that has 3 columns?

Tags: html, arrays, powershell

I have 3 arrays of strings (computer names):

```
$unreachable
$unresponsive
$noremote
```

I'm looking for a moderately elegant way to create a table that has column headers of "Unreachable", "Unresponsive" and "NoRemote"  with each of the columns being a list of the items from their respective array.

I'm probably overthinking this but I would appreciate the help of the hive mind.

Comment: i think i would build a new collection of custom objects with the columns you want set up as properties. then put the name of each comp in the property for that row.

Comment: Yep, what he said. Use a `For($i=0;$i -lt ($unreachable,$unresponsive,$noremote|% Count|sort|select -last 1);$i++){` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here was the solution (within a nice little DC monitoring script) that I ended up with.  thanks @TheMadTechnician for that.

```
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | sort-object Name
$unreachable=@()
$unresponsive=@()
$noremoteAD=@()
foreach ($DC in $DCs)
{
    $Name = $DC.Name
    $dateline=(Get-Date).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss - ") + $Name  
    #Write-Host $dateline

    if (!(Test-Connection $Name -quiet))
    {
        $unreachable+=$Name
        continue
    }
    try
    {
        $user = get-aduser "Brian.Hampson" -server $Name -properties Name -ErrorAction Stop
        #write-host "Good - $Name"
    }
    catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServerDownException]
    {
        $noremoteAD+=$Name
    }
    catch [System.TimeoutException]
    {
        $unresponsive+=$Name
    }
}
$DCCollection = @()


For($i=0;$i -lt ($unreachable,$unresponsive,$noremotead|% Count|sort|select -last 1);$i++)
{
   $MyDC = "" | select Unresponsive,Unreachable,NoRemoteAD
   if ($i -lt $unreachable.Length) {$MyDC.Unreachable=$unreachable[$i]}
   if ($i -lt $Unresponsive.Length) {$MyDC.Unresponsive=$unresponsive[$i]}
   if ($i -lt $NoRemoteAD.Length) {$MyDC.NoRemoteAD = $noremoteAD[$i]}
   $DCCollection+=$MyDC
}
$head = @"
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu')
  </style>
  <style>
    BODY{background-color:peachpuff; font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;}
    TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
    TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}
    TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod}
strong{color: green;}
  </style>
"@

If ($DCCollection.count -gt 5)
{
    $date = (get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
    $body= "<P><H2><B>These are the DC's that have some sort of issue as of $date </B></H2></P>"
    $body+=$DCCollection|ConvertTo-Html -Head $head
    $from="NoReply-"+$Env:COMPUTERNAME+"@ALSGlobal.com"
    $to = @("Some.User@Example.com")
    $bcc = @("SomeOtherUser@Example.com")
    Send-MailMessage -Bcc $bcc -To $to -From $from -Subject "DCs with issues" -BodyAsHtml $body -SmtpServer "SMTPSERVER.Example.com" 
}
```

A beautiful HTML table with columns of server names is mailed nightly (in case anyone else finds it useful)